# How to avoid having .htaccess redirects from applying to subdomain as well?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a client site where I've set up some 301 redirects since the URLs of a couple of pages have changed.

No problem there, they work like a charm. The problem is that they have a second site set up as a subdomain of the first, and the redirects are being applied to the subdomain as well.

How do I *just* have the redirects apply to the designated HTML files in the root?

Here is my current HTACCESS file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if subdomain then bail out
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^home\htm$ http://analystsolutions.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^membersolutions\.php$ http://analystsolutions.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^institutionalsolutions\.html$ http://analystsolutions.com/institutions [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^thebook\.html$ http://analystsolutions.com/book [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about\.html$ http://analystsolutions.com/about-us [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^assessment http://analystsolutions.com/equity-research-assessment [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with something like this:

```
# if subdomain then bail out
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^home\.htm$ http://analystsolutions.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^membersolutions\.php$ http://analystsolutions.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^institutionalsolutions\.html$ http://analystsolutions.com/institutions [L,NC,R=301]
# rest of your 301 rules here
```

**PS:** Also make sure these rules are before WP code i.e. just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it didn't work. Now my original redirects don't even redirect :)

Comment: Can you post your latest .htaccess with my suggestions. I suspect you probably have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` incorrect.

Comment: Looks alright but did your sub domain actually start with `subdomain`. I just wrote it as an example. You will need to put your actual sub domain name here: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]`

Comment: The subdomain is a .com (e.g. sitename.com) and replacing 'subdomain' with 'sitename.com' did not work. The subdomain is still redirecting.

Comment: +1 This should've worked. @Cynthia, just to give an example, if the main domain was `google.com` a sub-domain is like `mail` in `mail.google.com`. So, what Anubhava meant here was to use `^mail\. [NC]`. But, I believe you're probably using `^sitename.com\. [NC]` which is incorrect because it's not a sub-domain but an add-on domain. You probably need `^sitename\.com$ [NC]` there.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Thanks for the nice explanation. Cynthia: `sitename.com` isn't really a subdomain. Let me ask for which subdomain you don't want above rules to fire?